# Installing Windows Azure SDK for .NET 2.2 VS2012 failed

Tags: visual-studio-2012, azure-sdk-.net

I have VS2012 Ultimate Update 4 installed. I need to installed Windows Azure SDK for .NET 2.2. I install it from Web Platform Installer. When i try to create project using window azure cloud service project template. I get the error

"Creating projects requires Windows Azure Tools v2.2 to be installed"

I tried to install by standalone installer, but no success. Any Help for diagnose the problem?

Comment: Let me see if I understand this correctly, the SDK installs without any error messages, but won't be detected by Visual Studio 2012?

Comment: Yes. I tried 4 times atleast. twice by Web Platform Installer and twice by standalone

Comment: What does `Programs and Features` have to say about the azure tools?

Comment: It shows all the tools installed. It has Windows Authoring Tools, Emulator, Libraries and Azure Tools for VS2012 v2.2. I can see them from start menu and tried running emulator; Is running, but not from IDE. But its the template which seems to be broken, it seems

Comment: I am diagnosing this directory C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplatesCache. There seems to something wrong in VS2012 referencing Cloud Service template

Comment: I getting a  failure to install, no comprehensible reason given. I'm going to see if I can manually install the pieces. I can post the voluminous and uninformative log if requested.